# Assembly Code to C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to translate this assembly code to C and I need help. It has something to do with a while loop but i don't know what happens in the while loop. I've looked at it for a while and i'm sure it contains "while(something =! null)" then do something but I don't know what happens when the code does "movl" into %eax.

This section is the x86 assembly code that was compiled:

```
whilecode:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        jmp     .L20
.L22:
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    16(%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%ebp)
.L20:
        cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
        je      .L21
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    4(%eax), %eax
        cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax
        jne     .L22
.L21:
        cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
        setne   %al
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

This is the definition of a node:

```
typedef enum {CHAR,SHORT,INT} Type;

typedef struct node {
  Type   thetype;
  int     data;
  void   *opaque;
  struct node *ptr1, *ptr2;
} Node;
```

This is function definition for the while loop:

```
/* a while loop */
int whilecode(Node *somenode, int data)
{
  // FIX ME
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Commenting on what the assembly does:

```
whilecode:
    pushl   %ebp            // save caller's frame pointer
    movl    %esp, %ebp      // set up our frame pointer
                            // no local variables set up
    jmp     .L20            // jump to the entry point of the function body

.L22:                       // NOT the beginning of the function -- probably a loop body
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   // %eax = first argument
    movl    16(%eax), %eax  // %eax = %eax->fifth field
    movl    %eax, 8(%ebp)   // first argument = %eax
.L20:
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)     // compare first argument to 0
    je      .L21            // branch to exit if they're equal 
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   // %eax = first argument
    movl    4(%eax), %eax   // %eax = %eax->second field
    cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax  // compare %eax to second argument
    jne     .L22            // loop if not equal
.L21:
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)     // compare first argument to 0
    setne   %al             // set %al = 1 if they're not equal (0 otherwise)
    movzbl  %al, %eax       // zero extend %al to %eax
    popl    %ebp            // restore the callers stack frame
    ret
```

Now you have a struct definition and a prototype, so this ends up being:

```
int whilecode(Node *somenode, int data)
{
    while (somenode != 0 && somenode->data != data)
        somenode = somenode->ptr2;
    return somenode != 0;
}
```

searching a linked list for a node that contains a particular data value and returning true if it is found.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

```
whilecode:
        pushl   %ebp         `Push EBP to stack`
        movl    %esp, %ebp   `EBP = ESP`
        jmp     .L20         `goto L20`
.L22:
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax  `EAX = (EBP+8)`
        movl    16(%eax), %eax `EAX = (EAX+16)`
        movl    %eax, 8(%ebp)  `(EBP+8) = EAX`
.L20:
        cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
        je      .L21           `if (EBP+8) == 0 goto L21`
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax  `EAX = (EBP+8)`
        movl    4(%eax), %eax  `EAX = (EAX+4)`
        cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax 
        jne     .L22           `if (EBP+12) != EAX goto L22`
.L21:
        cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)    
        setne   %al            `if 0 != (EBP+8) Sets the byte in the AL to 1`
        movzbl  %al, %eax      `EAX = AL (zero ext)`
        popl    %ebp           `POP from stack to EBP (recover it)`
        ret                    `return`
```

EBP, ESP, EAX are 32 bit registers, AL is 8 bit register.

(EBP+8) is the value in the address of EBP plus 8 BYTES.

Just follow it and you'll understand the code, sorry I don't have time, good luck!

Comment: This is wrong in many different ways. You do not only confuse the source and destination registers, but you also seem to be thinking that `offset(register)` treats the offset in bits, which it does not.

Comment: Maybe I do wrong with the offset, please tell me where, but src and dst are correct: `MOV X, Y` --> `X := Y`

Comment: "(EBP+8) is the value in the address of EBP plus 8 bit." - no, plus 8 byte. Just take a look at the logic: if `mov x, y` means `x = y`, then the code does not make sense. Nor does the act of saving `ebp` on the stack. but it suddenly makes sense to save it (push it to the stack) when the value of the stack pointer is stored into it.

Comment: You confuse AT&T syntax with Intel syntax. This is AT&T syntax. In AT&T syntax the order of the operands is src, dest. In Intel syntax it's dest, src.

Comment: `setne %al` sets `al` to 1 if ZF = 0, **else** (if ZF = 1) it sets `al` to 0.